# PHP quicksort dates in multidimentional array

Tags: php, sorting, quicksort

I'm currently working on a project where I'm retrieving data from an API which needs to be sorted. I'm trying to use Quicksort to do the sorting, but it doesn't seem to go right. The data consists of a multidimensional array which looks like this:

```
[result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [event_id] => 1212584488-61324fd3ad2881-14436970
                    [schedule_id] => 1
                    [start] => 2022-02-01 08:45:00
                    [end] => 2022-02-01 09:45:00
                    [title] => title
                    [employee_note] => 
                    [club_id] => XXX
                    [activity_id] => 322801
                    [instructor_id] => 0
                    [attendees] => 0
                    [max_places] => 15
                    [bookable] => 1
                    [cancel_before_duration] => 0
                    [booking_in_advance_duration] => 6 days
                    [canceled] => 
                    [presence_saved] => 
                    [language] => 
                    [bookable_by_third_party] => 
                )
```

The array needs to be sorted by the start date, and my quick sort looks like this:

```
//Quicksort by start time
function quicksort($list, $from, $to)
{
    echo $from . " " . $to . "<br></br>";
    if ($from < $to) {
        $pivot = $list[$to];
        $i = $from;
        for ($j = $from; $j <= $to; $j++) {
            $comparing = $list[$j];
            if (strtotime($comparing["start"]) < strtotime($pivot["start"])) {
                $temp = $list[$i];
                $list[$i] = $comparing;
                $list[$j] = $temp;

                $i++;
            }
        }

        $temp = $list[$i];
        $list[$i] = $pivot;
        $list[$to] = $temp;

        quicksort($list, $from, $i - 1);
        quicksort($list, $i + 1, $to);
    }
    return $list;
}

$sortedList = quicksort($output["result"], 0, count($output["result"]) - 1);
```

The Quicksort generates the following output:

```
2022-02-01 08:45:00
2022-02-03 19:00:00
2022-02-03 20:00:00
2022-02-02 19:30:00
2022-02-04 19:30:00
2022-02-03 09:00:00
2022-02-05 09:00:00
2022-02-04 10:00:00
2022-02-05 09:45:00
2022-01-31 09:00:00
2022-02-03 10:00:00
2022-01-31 18:30:00
2022-01-31 19:30:00
2022-01-31 18:30:00
2022-01-31 20:15:00
2022-02-01 10:00:00
2022-02-01 09:00:00
2022-02-02 10:00:00
2022-02-02 09:00:00
2022-02-04 09:00:00
2022-02-01 10:00:00
2022-02-02 18:30:00
2022-02-01 19:30:00
2022-02-01 18:30:00
2022-02-01 18:30:00
2022-02-01 19:30:00
2022-02-03 18:30:00
2022-02-04 18:30:00
2022-02-02 20:30:00
2022-02-05 10:00:00
2022-02-05 11:00:00
2022-02-05 10:15:00
2022-02-06 10:00:00
2022-02-06 09:45:00
2022-02-05 10:00:00
2022-02-06 09:00:00
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be some learning exercise, or why would you implement the sorting algorithm yourself - and not just use `usort`?

Comment: I tried to use `usort` but wasn't able to get it to work, so I thought I would just try it by implementing it my self. But if you know how I would be able to use usort would be amazing!

Comment: You should be able to find all the info you need to implement it using usort, in that mentioned duplicate.

Comment: I think it does, thanks!